# How can I handle a potentially pre-filled form with Jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have this huge form that only gets pre-filled data if data already exists in a database. Otherwise, none of the text boxes should have the `value` parameter in them. I thought it would just ignore the `value` parameters if the variable I get data from does not exist. But instead, I get an error.

How to I handle this case? Will I have to do an if check before each text box in Jade like the following?

```
if (typeof(prefilled_data) !== 'undefined')
    input.form-control#prevalence(type="text", name="prevalence")
else
    input.form-control#prevalence(type="text", name="prevalence", value=prefilled_data.tb_burden_estimates.prevalence)
```

While I don't mind doing this (Sublime Text will help with all the copy-pasting), there are quite a few form fields, so it might get ugly. Is there a way to consolidate this into one check somewhere?

Comment: why not iterate over `prefilled_data.tb_burden_estimates` and use the children to fill in `name`, `id` and `value` if there's content?

Comment: That's a completely unrelated point. The whole object may or may not be there. Should I have if-statements before each form field?

Comment: I need this same question answered. It seems like a pain in the ass to have to put an if statement around every input. Did you ever find a workaround?

Comment: I've been working on and off on that project, so not yet. I'll try to remember to update this if I ever do find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

you seemed to be suggesting that the if statement's were going to be bulky/make the code hard to read if they were there.. my suggestion would be to programmatically create the inputs, there by reducing the if statements to a more manageable number and answering your question about being able to "consolidate this into one check somewhere"

**EDIT**

If you are looking to access data in js.. I have been known to use something like:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    window.prefilled_data = !{ JSON.stringify(prefilled_data) };
```

This will allow you then to access the global window.prefilled_data variable to get front end version of your data

Comment: Can the variables I send to Jade be accessed from the client-side JS? Or will I need to use rewrite some logic to load the form blank and use ajax to check if it needs to be pre-filled?

Comment: see edit if that's what you'd like to have access to.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
- if (typeof(prefilled_data) === 'undefined'){
-   prefilled_data = '';
- }
input.form-control#prevalence(type="text", value=#{prefilled_data})
```

if `prefilled_data` is undefined you just set a `''` value